# Excel IF Function..too many arguments

Tags: excel

I'm trying to figure out what I am doing wrong with this formula. It is returning the error "you've entered too many arguments for this function"

```
=IF(ROUND(d28=0,0,IF(b28<=$B$19,0,IF(AND($B$18="Fixed Balloon",b28=$B$20),d28,G28-f28))))
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: `IF` always takes 3 arguments. In Excel, it highlights matching parentheses, so if you step through it with your arrow key, In this case, your `ROUND` function embraces the entire set of arguments inside, so your outer `IF` only has one argument.

Answer (score 3):

Try it like this, putting `ROUND(d28,1)=0` instead of `ROUND(d28=0...`

```
=IF(ROUND(d28,1)=0,0,IF(b28<=$B$19,0,IF(AND($B$18="Fixed Balloon",b28=$B$20),d28,G28-f28)))
```

To make this clearer, showing what is happening, type it out in a text document in an indented format:

```
=IF(ROUND(d28,1)=0,
  0,
  IF(b28<=$B$19,
    0,
    IF(AND($B$18="Fixed Balloon",b28=$B$20),
      d28,
      G28-f28
    )
  )
)
```

Edit: ROUND takes 2 parameters, the first being the number to round, and the second being the number of digits to round to. I choose to make it round to one digit.

This could equally be written like this, which I find makes it easier to understand:

```
=IF(OR(ROUND(D28,1)=0,B28<=$B$19),
  0,
  IF(AND($B$18="Fixed Balloon",B28=$B$20),
    D28,
    G28-F28
  )
)
```